# Find a table in SMS line in EM

Tags: sql, ssms

In Enterprise Manager, you can expand the table list for a database, click in the table window, then type the name of the table you are looking for & you will be brought to it or the the closest match.

Is there any way of accomplishing the same functionality in SSMS??

AHIA,
LarryR....

Comment: ...yes. By expanding the list in the object explorer, and typing the name of the table?

Comment: Gotta ask: what are you trying to do?  The tables are already listed alphabetically in the Object Explorer.

Comment: - Sam...no it does not, expand tables, then type 'S' ----- Norla - I want to be able to type a table/SP/View name & SSMS go right to it instead of having to look through a hundred at times.

Comment: You tables are probably prefixed with `dbo.`. Try typing that first `dbo.S` and you should be fine in SSMS as well.

Comment: Mikael Eriksson....Thanks, I was standing so close to the trees, that I could not see the forest.  That works, imagine that. Post your comment as an answer & I will flag it that way.  Thanks!!!!